# Use of “in”, “that” and “on”

Tags: grammar, prepositions

1.In the/that moment.
2. At the/that moment.
What is the difference?

Also I read: 
1.”On another ocassion”
2. “In another ocassion”
what’s the difference?
Could I also use “at”?

Answer (score 2):

In the moment refers to something that was said or done while experiencing a feeling of fear, dread, happiness, excitement. In that moment is the same but referring to the past.

> His son won the race and the father burst into tears in the moment.

At that moment refers to two or more things happening at the same time.

> The car hit the curb, at that moment I saw the driver was on his phone.
>
> The car hot the curb, at that moment all hell broke loose.

At the moment refers to something happening now or a present condition.

> At the moment he is on the phone.
>
> At the moment we are not sure what has happened.

You can't use in or at at an occasion.